# How can I find certain words and print the line in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to print only the lines with the specific string I need.

I did this but I can't figure out what's wrong:

```
def find(text):
    fisier = file('catastrofa.txt')
    for line in fisier:
        if (text in line):
            print(line)

def main():

    find("David")

main()
```

Comment: What is not working? Does it print too many lines, too few? Lines without David?

Comment: Error:file not defined

Changed it to this 


        def find(text):
            #fisier = file('catastrofa.txt')
            for line in 'catastrofa.txt':
                if ("text" in line):
                    print(line)
    
    
        def main():
            find("David")
    
    
        main()


but won't work at all

Answer (score 3):

You open a file with [**`open(..)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), you can then iterate over the file *handler* (iterating over a file handler will iterate over the file in a *line-by-line* fashion):

```
def find(text):
    with open('catastrofa.txt') as fisier:
        for line in fisier:
            if (text in line):
                print(line)

def main():
    find("David")

main()
```

By default the mode in which you open the file is `'r'`, so you *read* the file (you can not write to it), and you read it as *text* (not *binary*).

Note that the path of the file is *relative* from the current directory (that *can* be the directory of the python file, but sometimes it is *not*).

Comment: It just keeps saying "file is not defined"

Comment: @doesn'tmatter: yes, somehow I mentioned, but forgot to replace it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file using open and use the readlines method for iterating line by line

```
def find(text):
    fisier = open('catastrofa.txt')
    for line in fisier.readlines():
        if (text in line.strip()):
            print(line)
    fisier.close()

def main():
    find("David")

main()
```

You can also use context manager that is `with` keyword that guarantees to close stream after you done, example already demonstrated by Willem Van Onsem

Comment: I would not use `readlines()`, since this unfortunately reads the entire file into memory. Imagine that this is a 200GiB file, then the program would crash, whereas performing iteration on the file handler will work in a cursor-fashion.

Comment: then you can use yield statement that will not overhead memory

Comment: instead of print(line) you can use yield line

Comment: it will, since the `.readlines()` is the culprit. If you perform `yield`, from the moment you actually let the function do work, it will first work towards the first yield, and thus load it into memory.

Comment: then can use yield with for line in fisier:  yield line , it gonna work, am right?

Comment: yes that will work. The problem is not the `print`, but the `.readlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use open('catastrofa.txt') instead of file('catastrofa.txt')
like this:

```
def find(text):
    fisier = open('catastrofa.txt','r')
    for line in fisier:
        if (text in line):
            print(line)

def main():

    find("David")

main()
```

Comment: Pro tip: use a context manager (with `with`), or at least `.close()` the file handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in fisier:
```

iterates over lines in file without removing line endings (usually the line return) so:

```
print(line)
```

will print the line and an empty line so it's better to write:

```
with open('catastrofa.txt') as fisier:
  for line in fisier:
    if text in line:
      print(line, end='')
```

to avoid extra line returns.